# rendering Html forms as pdf

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf-generation

I have two html tables(containing dynamic content stored in variables) along with headings and paragraphs. When the user clicks the download PDF button, he/she should be able to download one PDF of two pages containing the two tables.

I have read a lot of articles but I found no definite answer to this issue.Should I use jspdf or react-pdf for this scenario?

I am using react frontend and Nodejs backend.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

JSPDF is a perfect solution for converting tables into PDF in client-side. But if you want to do something from backend

Or you can refer to 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

for rendering it in the backend, and make express download it.

Comment: The issue is I want to have a two page pdf ( It is a necessary requirement) and in the working example of pdfjs on npm and https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d), the multipage does not work. Try downloading the multipage from that article and you'll see.

Comment: Can react-pdf be used for the same. I am unable to render html content as pdf using react-pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can call the window.print() method in componentDidMount() to print the complete div, though removing the footer through the script can be a challenge.

Using html2canvas with jspdf has a major drawback that the pdfs are blurred and their clarity varies with the page zoom, as it takes the screenshot of that portion. Hence, you must configure it correctly or compromise on quality.